# Is there a difference between these two methods to convert a double to a negative value?

Tags: c#, double

// Value is double

Is any difference? What is fast way for compiler to do this calculation?

```
value = System.Math.Abs(55.55);
this.Value = -value;

// or    
this.Value = System.Math.Abs(value) * (-1);
```

Comment: _What is fast way for compiler to do this calculation?_ You can measure yourself. From Eric Lippert: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster **then race your horses.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 8):

> Is any diference?

Absolutely. Consider:

```
double value = -5;
this.Value = -value; // Sets Value to 5
this.Value = Math.Abs(value) * -1; // Sets Value to -5
```

Focus on *correctness* and *simplicity* before performance. What are you actually trying to achieve? How is that most simply expressed?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the logic: the first assignment would make `this.Value` positive when `value` is negative, while the second one never produces a positive number.

Since these two statements perform different things, there is no point in comparing which one is faster. In general, though, it rarely makes sense to tune such tiny code snippets for performance, because the impact of micro-optimizations of this kind on the overall performance of your product is nearly always nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines of code does different things.

Using `-value` will change the sign, if the value was positive it will be negative, and if it was negative it will be positive.

Using `Math.Abs(value) * -1` will make the value negative, regardless of the original sign.

The second option can be done more efficiently using the unary negative operator:

```
this.Value = -System.Math.Abs(value);
```

You can also consider doing the comparison yourself instead of using `Math.Abs`, which may be even faster:

```
this.Value = value < 0 ? value : -value;
```